# Show that a diamond is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that $\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{y^2} \le1$ is closed?

So I mean the set $\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: |x|+|y| \le 1\}$

I want to show that this set is compact :-)

I already drawed the set, it's a diamond. But I'm not sure how to proof that it's closed....

Comment: What definitions of closed do you know?

Comment: set is closed if it contains all its limit points. OR it's closed if the complement is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the tools that you can use. For example, use that $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
f(x,y) = |x| + |y|
$$
is a continuous function and that the set $(-\infty,1]$ is closed.